# Any idea how to connect to this API?

Tags: php, html, api

I tried to find any widget to show Tinkoof's bank currency rate, because it changes every 60sec., but nothing.
Finally I [found this API](https://www.tinkoff.ru/api/v1/currency_rates), but there is no any documentation for it.

I tried to find any articles about parsing, but I guess there's no use in that because of absence of any tag.

I need to show the currency rate on my website via this API. Any idea? 
Big thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fetch the content You can use cURL or file_get_contents()

cURL version:

```
<?php

$url = "https://www.tinkoff.ru/api/v1/currency_rates";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$r = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$array = json_decode($r, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

file_get_contents version:

```
<?php
$r = file_get_contents('https://www.tinkoff.ru/api/v1/currency_rates');

echo "<pre>";
echo print_r(json_decode($r, true));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Both of them will work unless the remote website requires you to be human (has extra verifications to stop robot requests). cURL would be a better way if that were the case because you can fake a user agent using a header array.

Once you have the array build it's just a matter of accessing the required data. using $r as an array result of the remote json structure.

Comment: it seems strange, but the only thing, that shows it's <pre> tag. I have php v7.0 and server supports curl. I even checked my php.ini.

Comment: I am so sorry i had json_decode($r, $true) instead or json_decode($r, true) lol I edited my code lol happens when i code fast lol I also tested my code this time

Comment: BIG thanks! Really, thank you for help and for the explanation!

Comment: My pleasure ;-)

Comment: print_r PRINTS - and returns int(1) - echo here will take the int(1) returned by print_r, and print that, so it will contain whatever print_r printed, and 1 ... which is definitely not what you want. remove the echo. also, its vulnerable to XSS injection, tinkoff.ru can inject whatever evil javascript it wants, to protect against that (and against accidental characters that have special meaning in html) it needs to be html encoded. to fix both, do `echo htmlentities (print_r(json_decode($r, true),true), ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true );`

Comment: I changed that element into => echo $array["payload"]["rates"][42]["buy"];

But thank you for your advice!

Comment: @hanshenrik the print was just to show the output of the array for proof of concept. He will be passing the output as an array and should indeed sanitise before using each value later on. But that's not what he asked.

Comment: then at least put up a fair warning at the end, like `warning: this example code is vulerable to XSS injection due to lack html encoding`

Answer (score 0):

It looks pretty straightforward to me. For someone with a decent knowledge of PHP will do this, provided the output is:

[image]

Now with the above information, I would:

1. Get the result to PHP using `file_get_contents()`.
2. Parse the result as an array using `json_decode($contents, $true)`.
3. Using the above result, I would get display the value using: `$output["payload"]["rates"][0]["buy"]` or something similar.

At this time of writing, the above will get me `58`:

[image]